# can't find gem rspec-core (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException) when running on Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rspec

I am trying to run ruby spec tests in a Jenkinsfile.
However I have run into problems when executing this code:

```
sh 'rspec spec/unit/test_spec.rb'
```

This is the error:

> /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:271:in
>   'find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem rake (>= 0.a)
>   (Gem::GemNotFoundException)   from
>   /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:299:in
>   'activate_bin_path'   from
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin/rake:23:in ''    from
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval'
>     from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   ''

I am running Jenkins on an EC2 instance. The gem rspec-core is definitely installed, as I do a bundle install before running the spec test. I have also run the exact same test as the one on the instance itself instead of Jenkins and it works.
When I run `gem which rspec` on Jenkins, it gives me this error:

> ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library rspec

But when I run it on the instance, it returns
`/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rspec-3.6.0/lib/rspec.rb`

Both are using the global gemset.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to run the spec test by using

`sh 'bundle exec rake spec:unit'`

It uses the rake file instead of running the individual test itself, which is much more cleaner and clear.

This is what the rakefile looks like:

```
namespace :spec do
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:unit) do |t|`
        t.pattern = 'spec/unit/**/*_spec.rb'
    end
end

task default: ['spec:unit']
```

Which runs all the unit tests.

Comment: This was useful to me despite not using Jenkins, since the relevant bit is that your answer was to use ```bundle exec```.