# rails-rspec error cannot load such file -- rspec/core/formatters/progress_formatter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I've broken my rails-rspec. I switched to a different gemset to run a 3rd party test. When I returned to my 2.3.0(default) gemset, I had the following errors.

running rspec gets:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- rspec/core/formatters/progress_formatter (LoadError)
```

running rails generate rspec:install returns:

```
Could not find generator 'rspec:install'. Maybe you meant 'devise:install' or ...
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but errors persist.

Running `rspec -v` returns:

```
- rspec-core 3.6.0
- rspec-expectations 3.6.0
- rspec-mocks 3.6.0
- rspec-rails 3.6.1
- rspec-support 3.6.0
```

It seems that ruby cannot find rspec-core. I have tried the workaround from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673087/cant-find-gem-rspec-core-0-a-gemgemnotfoundexception-when-running-on-j) without success. Thank you in advance for any insight you might provide.

Running

> rails 4.2.0, ruby 2.3.0

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Running `bundle exec rspec` solved it for me.

Comment: If you have multiple versions of `rspec` (maybe different apps with different versions of Rails), `bundle exec` ensures you use the one that's defined in your Gemfile. If you run `rails` or `rake` without that, it's possible your system will try to run a different version.

Comment: To expand on above, `bundle exec rspec spec/<path_to_file>/file_spec.rb`. In other words, run the actual tests with the `bundle exec' prefix.

Comment: The issue here isn't running the wrong spec but using the wrong version of rspec

Comment: It still doesn't explain why it works. I only have one version of `rspec`. `>gem list --local rspec`: `rspec-core (3.8.0)`. Same version as when I use `rspec -v`. So why would `bundle exec` make any difference?

Comment: If you don't want to have to type `bundle exec rspec` every time, do this: Run `gem list | grep rspec` and pay attention to any gems that list multiple versions.  then run `gem uninstall ______` for each of those versions (removing ALL of the versions of each).  then run `bundle` afterward.  This will sync your versions with the versions in your gemfile.

Answer (score 76):

Running `bundle clean --force` did the trick for me, turns out there's some outdated gem in my system

Comment: Also worked for me. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: This worked for me, but I have no idea what it is doing or why it is working. OP (and future readers) - if you know, that would be very much appreciated. chrs

Comment: Looks like running the embedded Rubymine test module broke the command line "rspec ./test.spec" for me.

Running it with "bundle exec rspec ./test.spec" also worked, but "bundle clean --force" fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

I learned this from Victor Hazbun - expert on CodeMentor and Egghead.io:

Run `gem list | grep rspec` and pay attention to any gems that list multiple versions.

Then run `gem uninstall ______` for each of those versions (removing ALL of the versions of each).

Then run `bundle` afterward.  This will sync your versions with the versions in your gemfile.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the error below in a rails app and none of the solutions here worked for me.

```sh
gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:210:in `require': cannot load such file -- rspec/core/formatters/progress_formatter (LoadError)
```

Emptying the gemset and re-installing did.

This assumes you are using `rvm` and a `.ruby-gemset` at the root of your app.

```sh
$ rvm gemset empty <name-of-gemset>
$ bundle install
```

Comment: Nobody else responded, but this one worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try

```
bundle exec rspec:install
```

Comment: This is just flat out wrong. Should not be marked as correct answer.

Comment: As the above commenter pointed out, this solution fails with a command not found error. The syntactically correct command would be `bundle exec rails g rspec:install`, but this still didn't fix this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to make a contribution to CocoaPods and was getting the same error when I was doing `rspec foo_spec.rb`. Turns out they were NOT using `rpsec` at all. They seem to have had a special test runner:

> CocoaPods uses bacon as a test runner. To run all tests, use `bundle exec rake spec` in the *root* of the project. If you want to run a specific test instead, use `bundle exec bacon spec/[folder]/[name]_spec.rb`

For more on that see [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10417#issuecomment-775602745)

Answer (score 0):

If you run the specs from RubyMine, you can specific the RSpec version in Run Configuration.

[image: Configuration Modifications]